# Blur Activity Background with Swipe in android

Tags: android, swipe, android-gesture

I need to blur activity background when i swipe from Right to Left and Left to Right. I have read about Blur or dim background when Android PopupWindow active and dim background with `FLAG_DIM_BEHIND`. but can't use this because this use to dim everything behind current window. in my case there are no other windows. in my app, do some changes on same activity with swipe gesture.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Dimming Activity....

getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations=R.style.PauseDialogAnimation;
        getWindow().getAttributes().flags=WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        getWindow().getAttributes().dimAmount=0.5f;
```

Comment: what is `R.style.PauseDialogAnimation` ?

Comment: I have no dialog box. Read the question clearly. i mentioned it as **in my case there are no other windows.**

Comment: why should i remove that line ?

Comment: but still no changes. screen is not dimmed

Comment: yeah. it's working for dialog. but not in my case, because i have no Dialog :(